# Where do files downloaded using wget usually go to on Pop_OS?

Tags: linux, wget

I recently ran a download speedtest using:

```
wget --output-document=/dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test500.zip
```

I got the output:

```
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 524288000 (500M) [application/zip]
Saving to: ‘/dev/null’

/dev/null           100%[===================>] 500.00M  11.7MB/s    in 46s     

2022-12-31 22:38:11 (10.9 MB/s) - ‘/dev/null’ saved [524288000/524288000]
```

Now I am not sure where to find this file; I naturally looked at `dev`, but it has no `null` file or subdirectory. Now I am not sure where this file is. As this is a test file, I would prefer to delete it.

Comment: "I naturally looked at `dev`, but it has no `null` file or subdirectory" – If you mean `/dev` and if it's true there is no `/dev/null` in your OS, then it's a pathological situation and things or the entire OS may misbehave. Hopefully a restart will fix this.

Comment: And if a restart does not fix it, maybe [shut down this system and wait for the singularity](https://xkcd.com/1084/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I am not sure where to find this file (`/dev/null`)

You sent your output to `output-document=/dev/null`.

> As this is a test file, I would prefer to delete it.

You don't need to as it doesn't exist.

> It’s a special file that’s present in every single Linux system. However, unlike most other virtual files, instead of reading, it’s used to write. **Whatever you write to `/dev/null` will be discarded, forgotten into the void**. It’s known as the null device in a UNIX system.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [What is /dev/null and How to Use It](https://linuxhint.com/what_is_dev_null/)

---

Further Reading:

- [Overview of /dev/null | Linux.org](https://www.linux.org/threads/overview-of-dev-null.11641/)
- [Step by step breakdown of /dev/null | by Jorge Yau | Medium](https://medium.com/@codenameyau/step-by-step-breakdown-of-dev-null-a0f516f53158)

Comment: Wow, this is neat!

Comment: /dev/null is great for testing file output, without actually creating the files on the filesystem